# I can't insert data into my database

Tags: php, mysql

I don't know why, but my data doesn't go into my database 'users' with the table 'data'.

```
<html>
<body>
<?php

date_default_timezone_set("America/Los_Angeles");

include("mainmenu.php");

$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "g00dfor@boy");
 if(!$con){
  die(mysql_error());
}

$usrname = $_POST['usrname'];
$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$lname = $_POST['lname'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

mysql_select_db(`users`, $con) or die(mysql_error());

mysql_query(INSERT INTO `users`.`data` (`id`, `usrname`, `fname`, `lname`, `email`, `password`) VALUES (NULL, '$usrname', '$fname', '$lname', '$email', 'password')) or die(mysql_error());

mysql_close($con)

echo("Thank you for registering!");

?>    
</body>
</html>
```

All i get is a blank page.

Comment: First, I see no semicolon after mysql_close(). Next, enable PHP debug output and see PHP log - it will tell you, what kind of error happens.

Comment: First of all you don't have the <?php tag opened properly.

Comment: FIRST OF ALL, DON'T USE CAPS!!! (I edited it out for you)

Comment: I also strongly recommend to [secure the saved passwords](http://chargen.matasano.com/chargen/2007/9/7/enough-with-the-rainbow-tables-what-you-need-to-know-about-s.html), regardless your usecase!

Comment: also edit your error_report settings with `error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT)` to see your parse errors during development

Comment: thanks all for the answers! it now displays "Thank you for registering", but it doesnt put the form data into the data table. i just added a semicolon to mysql_close(), and quotes to mysql_select_db(). whats up?

Comment: and about the opening php bracket- i have it fine on my txt doc, i just accidentally deleted it while typing.

Comment: You also have security issues with this.  Research SQL Injection vulnerabilities and why you should not store unhashed, unsalted passwords in a database.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you need to enclose the query you give to `mysql_query()` in double quotes<sup>1</sup>:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO ... ");
```

You also need to terminate your call to `mysql_close()` with a semicolon, as others pointed out.

---

<sup>1</sup> The same applies for `mysql_select_db()`, as [@marcog](https://stackoverflow.com/users/89806/marcog) pointed out in the comment below.

Answer (score 1):

because of this line

```
mysql_close($con)
```

you forgot semicolon

```
mysql_close($con);
```